# R: Changing height/location of column labels

Tags: r

Using the following code, the column labels for my barplot overlap with the plot itself (see image).  Changing the margin appears only to affect the axis label, but not the column labels.  Did a search but couldn't find this question. Suggestions?  Thank you! (P.S.--I'm a beginner!)

```
library(colorspace)

df <- matrix(c(20, 14, 26, 18, 14, 4, 19, 21, 13, 1, 5, 4), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(df) <- c("Character", "Tree", "Distance")
colnames(df) <- c("nrITS", "trnH-\npsbA", "matK", "rbcL")
graph.dat <- as.table(df)
italic_latin2 <- c(expression(atop(italic("nrITS"), (104))), 
                   expression(atop(italic("trnH-\npsbA"), (82))), 
                   expression(atop(italic("matK"), (42))), 
                   expression(atop(italic("rbcL"), (28))))
barplot(graph.dat, beside = TRUE, ylab = "Percent Identified", 
        xlab = "Locus", ylim = c(0, 30), col = rainbow_hcl(3), 
        names.arg = italic_latin2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code works perfectly but I'm not sure I understand how you came to this conclusion in finding the padj parameter to adjust the positioning.  I am creating a figure with similar labeling (using "atop()) from a dataframe using the boxplot() function, and padj does not work in this case.  I have tried to search for the new parameter that will modify the column label height, but have been unable to find it...

Answer (score 1):

Look at where the `?barplot` function arguments get sent by the `...` parameter values. The `?axis` page says there is a `padj` parameter to adjust vertical label positioning, so perhaps:

```
italic_latin2 <- expression( atop(italic("nrITS"), (104)), 
                   atop(italic("trnH-\npsbA"), (82)), 
                   atop(italic("matK"), (42)), 
                   atop(italic("rbcL"), (28)) )
barplot(graph.dat, beside = TRUE, ylab = "Percent Identified", 
        xlab = "Locus", ylim = c(0, 30), col = rainbow_hcl(3), 
        names.arg = italic_latin2, padj=0.8)
```

Notice that I simplified the expression vector code as well. The arguments to `expression` are adequately separated by commas.

[image]